# shaders SEUS error / sky overlay

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-shader

I have the ATLauncher, and i was looking around for shaders and found SEUS, so i directly installed it into my skyfactory 2 instance folder.

I followed all the instructions, correctly, yet still had a few problems.

[image]

Notice the lack of colours, and the cloud coming through.

I also get the error:

```
[shaders] Error: Invalid program gbuffers_textures_lit
```

I am currently running SEUS v10.1 (supposedly works for 1.7.10)

With a minecraft version 1.7.10.

Comment: What graphics card does your computer have?

Comment: intel hd graphics @SevenSidedDie

Answer (score 2):

[SEUS doesn't run correctly on Intel HD Graphics](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/mods-discussion/2322361-got-seus-shaders-running-on-intel-graphics-just?comment=3) because that GPU and its drivers do not support the shaders features that SEUS uses. That's SEUS *the mod*, not any one shader pack—the mod is simply incompatible with your graphics system and switching packs won't help.

There is currently no fix from Intel for this. There will be no fix from SEUS for this because SEUS is not intended to be run on low-powered graphics systems like integrated Intel graphics.

Comment: which shader-pack would you next recommend? @SevenSidedDie

Comment: It's not the shader pack, it's the whole mod that does not support Intel graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Sildur's Shaders for intel 1.03 will work perfectly.